# iOS WKWebView get touch event position relative to the device screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-webview, wkwebview

I'm working on a JS SDK that will run inside a WKWebView / WebView on iPhone and Android devices.

On the JS code, I'm listening to touch and mouse events and collecting data like the touch position.

On Android, all works as expected, IE:
`event.screenX` is a value relative to the device screen and `event.clientX` is a value relative to the WebView client area.

On iOS `event.clientX == event.screenX`. P.S all is relevant to the Y value too.

**Q**: is there a way to get touch event position relative to the screen?